# SignIn with oidc-client-js and redirect to another web application

Tags: angular, authentication, openid-connect, oidc-client-js

I'm struggling with the authentication process. Not sure if it's well designed.

[image]

I have an angular app just for the login and registrations of users. In case the user wants to login `1`, he fills only an email field and then he will be redirected `2` to the authentication page (its another website using identityserver4) there he can enter his password. And finally, last redirection to the angular app, he want to access initially `3`.

I'm using the [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js).

The problem I have is, that I can not complete the authentication. Calling `signinRedirectCallback` gets the `No matching state found in storage` error. I thought the informations, code, state, session_state, etc. (received from the auth-service via query params) are enough to complete the authentication. But it doesn't seem that way...

Should that process work somehow? Or should I integrate the login component in each of my apps, so the redirect after login `3` comes back to same app and the storage state will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process (workflow) I tried was wrong. 
To complete the authentication I have to redirect back to login.mydomain.ch because of PKCE (Proof Key for Code Exchange). Once back at login.mydomain.ch I can redirect from there to another app. Because IdentityServer supports SSO (single sign on) the user don't have to login again.

Answer (score 0):

It should work like this:

- The Angular app implements the client side of open id connect 
  and redirects to Identity Server, then receives the login response
- You are already using the best library in oidc-client-js, which will do most of this for you
- Logins and user sign up are completely externalised from your app and triggered by Identity Server during a login redirect

Most companies use a cloud authorization server and don't have to code any of the externalised security. As an example see [this AWS write up](https://medium.com/@eelkevdbos/how-to-managing-user-registration-and-login-using-aws-cognito-9d5b51034d13) for how built in functionality is used.

If you are using Identity Server you'll need to get it to do the same thing. It has extensibility points to enable this but it may turn into quite a bit of work.